# How to professionally tell my boss to not contact me during my holidays?

Tags: professionalism, communication, holidays, belgium

I'm currently on holidays, and I'm a software developer.

For the first time in my 10+ years of work, my boss tried to reach me during my holidays, on my private phone (while I have a company phone that I left turned off at home). It's not my project manager who would normally call me for daily emergencies, but my actual hierarchical superior with whom I interact between one and two times a month, sometimes less. He's the one who had the final word in giving my my holidays. I couldn't answer the phone because where I am, I barely have any network, and if I had heard the call, I wouldn't have answered anyways (because it costs me very much, being abroad).

Additionally, I contacted him once during his holidays, on his work e-mail, explicitly stating that the matter could wait until his return. That time, he answered me back within the hour. I didn't expect him to do so, and now I feel I have to answer him because of that, but I don't want to. I took all precautions to let him disconnect entirely. He didn't, and now I feel he expects me to not disconnect entirely as well.

I want to enjoy my holidays to the fullest and would like to send a text message to tell him to stop trying to contact me and that I will deal with whatever he wants upon my return, just like my "Out of Office" message says. How to professionally formulate anything that will convey my ideas?

Comment: If you send a message it means that you _can_ send a message. If you _can_ send a message, all your reasoning about not being able to answer falls down. Don't send a message. If you can't answer you _can't_ answer.

Comment: Did you put appropriate cover in place while you were on leave?  Did you have an out-of-office e-mail responder?  Did you designate a colleague who can handle matters while you are out?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Why wouldn't OP be aware of that expectation if it actually existed? Wouldn't OP's boss need to have made that explicitly clear *prior* to OP being hired, or at least at the moment it changed after the fact?

Comment: How many times did he try to reach you?  From your description it sounds like it was one call, but you ask how to tell him to stop which makes me think he's being persistent.

Comment: General response to all: - yes I put general cover: my direct colleagues are aware of everything; - my hierarchical superior was hired two years ago while I'm for 6 years in this company. All previous managers said they won't call me whatever the need; - Monica, it's indeed one time, but I do not want to set a precedent. My holidays are sacred for me. I value my quality of life much, much more than each individual job (but "working" is part of my quality of life).

Comment: Simple answer - block his number during the holiday - most modern phones can block numbers and you can always unblock later.. If it's important he'll email you when he can't contact you via telephone. Emails can then simply be "Hi boss, Thanks for the heads up. This can wait till I return, see you on X!"

Comment: @walen: _Can_ does not imply _at arbitrary times_, though. E.g., when you're in a house without electricity or where there is barely connectivity; it could be that you then go shopping/internet only every few days (I've experienced that personally, and one of my "affiliates" [I mean a neutral way to mean wifes/husbands/friends/etc.] lives like that). Also consider https://www.visitnorway.com/plan-your-trip/travel-tips-a-z/right-of-access/ as an example. So, being able to communicate does not necessarily break down the reasoning behind not being available all the time.

Comment: @phresnel I'm aware of that, but OP does not want their boss to stop contacting them just at certain times or places. OP wants their boss to stop contacting them while on holidays, no contact whatsoever, at any time or place, period. And intends to use "physical inability to send or receive calls or messages" as a reason to be offline 24/7 during holidays, whether true or not. The moment OP sends a message while on holidays, they are blowing that cover.

Comment: When I'm "off the grid" I give my management my *mother's* phone number and tell them that if it is really so urgent, they can explain the situation to my mom, and she knows how to reach me. Oddly enough, no one has ever tried to contact me while I'm on vacation, even though my mom is super nice.

Comment: @EricLippert, Your solution is my favorite, you should put it down as an answer. Having a trusted parent or a relative screen the calls is pure genius.

Comment: "For the first time in my 10+ years of work, my boss tried to reach me during my holidays, on my private phone (while I have a company phone that I left turned off at home)." --- Can you explain whether you feel your work phone was previously and regularly used to inappropriately contact you?  Or is this the first instance in 10 years you've been contacted on holiday?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I beg to differ from my other posters. You are in a different country, it costs you time and money to contact them. More importantly, it takes your mind off holiday.

**Don’t answer at all.** If you get back home, just blame it on the roaming that you could not answer. Just because your boss is setting a bad example by working his holidays does not mean you should follow. If he didn’t know you were on holiday - it’s the responsibility of you organisation to organize holiday-calendars.

If they have some absolutely urgent life or death thing going on, they’ll continue trying to reach you, send you an SMS, an e-mail etc. Then you can call them back when it is convenient to you. Make sure to not let you be compelled to help them if you feel it is not urgent. You can’t really remember right now, have no computer available etc. They’ll get used to what ever standard you set for your holiday-availability so don’t blow it by doing them a one-time favor.

Comment: Accepted answer for the "they'll get used to whatever standard you set for your holidays". It solves the issue now, once and for all.

Comment: Maybe the´ll try some again some time. I discovered that when I came back to office, often it was not a big deal and sometimes they´d already forgotten there was this thing ...

Comment: +1, however I think applying a few days of delay between each answer to the manager would be enough to discourage him/her of trying again, and it'd be more respectful than ignoring them. Not being helpful in a first time might work too, by example the first answer could be `Hi XXX, I'v just seen your message, did you already figure this out ?`

Comment: I´d beg to differ. Not answering send another message, being "I did not even get your request" which might actually be more polite. Also, to call back after a few days means that you have to keep it in your mind - holidays are to get your mind off of work. Last, anything that could wait a few days can also wait a few more day´s till you are back on paid time. (Assuming you do not usually have a month-long holiday)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd even "blame it on the roaming". When you get back and people ask why you didn't respond, point out that it was a *work* message, and you were *on holiday*. Unless your job requires you to be on call, that's all the explanation you need. If they're being extraordinarily persistent to the point where you feel it may be an emergency, *then* maybe answer it, but even then, only to the extent necessary to determine whether it is an emergency, and resolve it to the point where the rest can wait til your holiday is over. (and if it isn't an emergency, just go back to ignoring it).

Comment: This is great advice. In addition, I would recommend preparing your coworkers with this expectation by using some kind of messaging on your email auto-reply when you are on holiday that essentially says, "due to travel I will not have access to my email or phone."

Comment: "Not answering" only makes the most sense when combined with however you're announcing your leave to your boss and co-workers. If you make it clear you'll be out of the country and difficult to get a hold of, then the default expectation will be that you won't be able to answer your phone if someone does try to contact you. Just like everything else you do as a software developer, ensure you set appropriate expectations.

Comment: The general work agreement I have has a clause dealing with this, if i am abroad it automatically triggers a travel allowance for that day. And if it takes a nontrivial time to do then it drops one paid vacation day back to my pool of unspent days. You simply do not contact people on holidays, since the point of a holiday is to disconnect from work. Each interruption is counterproductive to this goal.

Comment: -1 for the encouragement to lie about the roaming. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil "`If you make it clear that you'll be out of the country`". I disagree. The employer has no business knowing what/where OP will/won't be doing/going during his off-time. Whenever I took FTO, my location in the Calendar would say "Not @work". That's all they *need* to know. If you wish to say more, that's up to you, but they should learn to respect that.

Comment: @ray: That depends on what your responsibilities are. Many software developers have an expectation of being available in a reasonable amount of time during off-hours if there's a fire in production systems, so that expectation may need to be reset as necessary. If I'm staying home and simply taking the week off and the production system melts down, I'd probably expect a call from my supervisor asking if I can lend a hand. If your job responsibilities don't go past 9-5 under any circumstances, then sure, I suppose you can be brief and vague.

Comment: @Ellesedil: If the employer has such an expectation, I would guess they communicate it beforehand, so I assumed the situation would be no emergency standby responsibility. Btw. I absolutely think being on standby is also a kind of (low intensity) work - and I have had employers who would compensate this.

Comment: @Daniel: I have been compensated for after-hours work previously, usually in the form of a bonus or additional PTO. But that context has been usually in a "We need a new thing on a tight deadline." Just so I'm clear: I would normally expect not be contacted in most situations. But if you want to ensure that, then you need set the appropriate expectation. If your colleagues *know* you won't be available by any means, then they won't contact you unless under only the most exceptional circumstances, such as production issues costing the company a lot of money for it's size.

Comment: @Ellesedil: That may be culturally dependent, but I would consider it rude to be contacted with work-related issues by default. (catastrophes aside) I would argue that my employer would have to set expectations by asking me if he could contact me during my off-time. Nonetheless, it is done a lot - just like playing with your cellphone when you are at dinner with someone - does not  make it less rude. Technically it would also be unlawful around here (Germany) to ask this of your employees.

Comment: My strategy was to answer very late in the evening. "Sorry, I was at the beach and left my phone locked in hotel safe. Did you figure this out?"

Answer (score 38):

I'm going against the current trend but I think you **should answer**. I'm assuming that your boss had a good reason to CALL you. He didn't send you an e-mail (even on your private e-mail address) which you can read when you want. He CALLED YOU. I may be wrong but to me it means he had a compelling reason to do so. You didn't answer and it's absolutely your right.

Imagine, just for example, you changed (or you're the only one to know) the administrator's password of an internal service. Are you willing to block all the other employees until you come back from your holidays for an *issue* you can solve in 1 minute? Worse, imagine that this was your fault. The limit is just imagination and there may be many [other possible reasons](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99209/how-to-professionally-tell-my-boss-to-not-contact-me-during-my-holidays/99275?noredirect=1#comment303253_99275).

**Unless otherwise proved you should assume good faith, no malice and no abuses.**

What I'd do? I'd send him an e-mail (a phone call may be better). IMMEDIATELY. You had the time to discuss this issue here then you probably have 5 minutes for this. Just two lines where you politely and respectfully explain that you don't have network but for *emergencies* he can send you an e-mail and you will *try* to answer as soon as possible. The message is clear (if you feel you really need to convey this message) but you **behave with responsibility** and in a **professional way**. You also have the opportunity to decide if it's an emergency or not (in case he will behave unprofessionally this or another time), obviously with greater responsibilities will come also *annoying* episodes (and how you handle them is the screen of your maturity for *higher* duties).

---

If you worry that *someone else* (I'm still assuming that your boss will behave professionally) will try to contact you and you do not want to set a precedent then you may follow the wonderful [Eric Lippert's tip](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99209/how-to-professionally-tell-my-boss-to-not-contact-me-during-my-holidays/99275#comment303441_99209) but for now I think you should deal with *this* case.

Comment: I can think of several reasons for a call. For example, if a colleague I knew well had died I might want to send condolences and flowers before the funeral, rather than waiting until my return. If the entire office had been laid off it might be better to know immediately rather than come back to find a locked door. Even things that the PM would normally communicate might come through the hierarchical manager if they both felt contacting you on vacation was a really serious step.

Comment: "..you should assume good faith, no malice and no abuses". I agree. At least for people that you know personally. It makes live so much easier if you do.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek absolutely!

Comment: I agree. Note also that the this is the first time in over 10 years that this happens, and it's the boss himself who calls. This doesn't have the signs of lightly assuming you'd be available during your holiday. I'd call back. If it's a non-critical issue, you can quickly decline to deal with the issue. All you've lost is a few minutes. However, if it is critical, and you're the only one able to fix a costly crisis, it will pay off.

Comment: I agree with this answer 100%. Its the first time this has happened and nowadays we do not live in a bubble. Unless the OP is pretty close to the bottom of the totem pole and doesn't have any real responsibilities,it is very possible that something was done that can't necessarily wait until the end of your holiday without significant loss to the employer. The professional thing to do is to answer the call and if it is unimportant let them know you will attend to it on your return. You don't want to come home from holiday and be the reason the company suffered significant losses.

Comment: I disagree.  If the purpose of the call was for anything serious they would leave a voicemail and follow it up with an urgent email and/or text asking the OP to get in touch as soon as possible.  If they didn't do any of those things then it was just some minor need for information that wasn't important enough to really bother someone on vacation - in other words it is completely ignorable.

Comment: @NotMe I disagree because all we can do are **speculations**. Voicemail may be off, he may have sent an e-mail to OP's work address (maybe because he doesn't know his private one), just for example. Maybe the question needed an answer immediately (because boss was together with a customer and they needed to solve a major issue, in this case the _damage_ has been already done and OP should show just goodwill). Let me repetitive: without any other evidence (1st call in 10 years) we MUST assume good faith. I think OP is well within his rights to behave in this way, it's just not what I'd suggest

Comment: This is dead wrong.  Unless your work agreement has stated in advance, preferably at the time of hire or promotion into your current job slot, that you are on call,  there is nothing that can't wait until you get back to the office.   If you're the only one with the admin password, then the head of IT needs to be fired for incompetence.  If a coworker died, they can send you a note that you'll receive at home before getting to the office.  And so on.

Comment: @Carl of course that's another opinion. **I** will be ready to help if it will take 1 minute of time regardless what's on my contract. **I** will appreciate they inform me if a close colleague died to send condolences to their family as soon as possible. I understand your (and OP) reasons but I really can't agree with them.

Comment: Nope, assuming good faith, no malice and no abuses by your superiors is something you might be able to do if you work for a _very_ good company. Your superiors are not your friends and 8 out of 10 times (and that's optimistic) their least priority is your well-being, and their top priority is meeting company goals. Holidays exist only for one reason, to disconnect for a prolonged period of time, if you don't do that you are going to become sick sooner or later.

Comment: @r41n _"...Your superiors are not your friends..."_ we don't need to be friends (even if sometimes they have been and it's definitely better) but at least, IMO, we should cooperate to meet company goals and a _good_ healthy company will make its employees happy, somehow (possibly but not necessarily with money). Maybe I've just been lucky and I will change my mind in future but in 20 years and few companies I never had to regret this POV. From a pragmatic point of view I'd also say that someday you may need a small favor from them (In Italy we say _"Una mano lava l'altra e tutte e due..."_)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti being friends is not the point. Expecting "good faith" from people on a pro level is generally speaking naive. People will try to get from you what they need, often without even realizing it. If you give them what they want, a standard is set, that will be pushed as long as you allow it. It's that easy, and the reason why contracts exist. It doesn't get more pragmatic than this. Ignoring contracts (or getting butt-hurt about them) and doing "favors", is, BTW and IMO, one of the major reasons why Italy is such a financial mess, and people move away from there (including me).

Comment: @r41n expecting "good faith" ESPECIALLY at pro level is not naive (IMO) but what SHOULD be a standard and professional behavior. If you can't build trust then you hardly can work well together. I agree about Italy (I already moved away...) and I found here in The Netherlands that "good faith unless otherwise proved" is the _default_ and I definitely love it.

Answer (score 18):

You've done what you can.

All you can do is quite clearly state that you're on vacation and don't have a reliable connection or capacity to work.

All you can really do is give a brief answer, provide an alternative resource if you have one (someone else who can provide fuller answers) and enjoy the rest of your vacation.

And then ignore future voicemail/emails unless they're business critical in nature.

Comment: Actually, even if it is business critical in nature, there is no good reason to contact the OP.  In fact, there are actually no good reasons I can think of that requires this.  Even if the company is found to be doing illegal activities, and they have a warrant out for his arrest, this will be handled when the OP comes home.  The only thing I can think of is family emergencies.

Comment: *In fact, there are actually no good reasons I can think of that requires this*: **one**. The company needs a new manager, you're on top of the short-list, are you interested? If yes, can you be here within 2 days to get the job, sign the contract, and get the $$$ bonus? **OK boss, BRB**.

Comment: @OldPadawan even for that it seems weird that it can't wait for a few days.

Comment: @Erik : fair enough. **I** wouldn't be bothered in that case :)

Comment: IGNORE THE CALLS after fair warning is given.

Comment: @OldPadawan: I’ve had exactly such a case where I was on holidays, a new position opened up and my manager contacted me to suggest I apply as quickly as possible.

Comment: @OldPadawan That's super contrived.  If they want the employee as a manager, they can certainly wait until he's back from his vacation.

Comment: @Andy perhaps being manager implies more responsability and less holidays, and thus you need to show you're up for the task? I'm not saying managers should have less holidays but I wouldn't be surprised if it were an expectation.

Comment: @PierreArlaud A promotion would normally give you MORE time off (and money), not less.  A good company to work for would wait until the employee is back to talk about a promotion; a terrible company would make the employee give up the remainder of his time off to "prove" he's up for the task.  Maybe if the employee was *already* a manager and an emergency came up, being called on vacation would be understandable, but what you're suggesting sound pretty unprofessional to me.

Answer (score 8):

Don't. You're on holiday. Whatever it is, it can wait until you get back. But of course you can't do that, the thought will keep nagging you.

Try to reach him via phone or email. Ask what the emergency is. To be fair it might as well be an emergency, but you don't know yet.

I would assume competency and brace for extenuating circumstances, at least for show. If it turns out it's nothing urgent, there's nothing wrong with saying

> I'm on holiday. I don't expect to be contacted on the phone for anything other than an emergency

...after you verify that he *knows* you're on holiday. If you think this brusque or curt, remember that the guy interrupted you in the middle of your holidays, which means he doesn't know where your boundaries lie.

Comment: `Ask what the emergency is.` - I am very strongly in the camp that believes that if something is an emergency the caller would mention that in the voicemail, email, text, etc and ideally include what the problem is and why it is urgent.  A message with no content is not an emergency.

Comment: @Zoredache True. My thinking is to give the benefit of doubt, as in _Hello! I have a missed call. What's the emergency?_ This establishes that you expect to be disturbed in the case of emergency only. A bit passive-aggressive I admit, but there we go.

Answer (score 3):

It seems no one noticed the following (emphasis added):

> I contacted him once during his holidays, on his work e-mail, explicitly stating that the matter could wait until his return. That time, he answered me back within the hour. I didn't expect him to do so, and now **I feel** I have to answer him because of that, but I don't want to. I took all precautions to let him disconnect entirely. He didn't, and now **I feel** he expects me to do not disconnect entirely as well.

This is your *feeling.*  You're overthinking this.

You already told him the matter could wait until his return.  He decided to answer early.  For all you know, he is expecting that *you* won't see **his** answer until *you* return from holidays.

Just mark the email as unread and let it sit there until the end of your holidays.  Absolutely nothing wrong has happened here.

---

I reread your question, and it's a little bit unclear whether the phone call from him came before or after the email.  I don't think this modifies the situation at all, though.

In the future I recommend you not send work emails while you are on holidays.  But the simplest and best solution *now* is to **enjoy your holiday** and do your work when you return.

---

IF the matter comes up when you return, I wouldn't even discuss the holiday aspect.  Just talk about the work.  "Hey, I was trying to reach you about ____ project."  "Yes, how is that project going?  What do you need?  Etc."  This is much better than "Yes, but I was on holiday, you shouldn't have called me," and starting an argument about it.

Comment: Precision: the e-mail I sent was while I wasn't on holidays, but he was. Two days ago, he tried to call me. -- now indeed, you seem to be the only one to notice my use of the word "feel", and thank you for addressing that bit, I... feel... it's important ;-)

Comment: @Someone, ah, that definitely affects the situation.  In that case, I actually agree with [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/99275/47537).  There may be some emergency going on that's *not* just a project emergency, but something more drastic.  If it turns out that's not the case, you can ask the person involved to please use emails only (not phone calls) when you're on vacation unless it's truly a life or death matter.  But better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Wildcard: Completely agree with that assessment. We don't know what responsibilities or knowledge expertise compared to his/her colleagues the employee has, so the phone call may have been warranted (although an email or IM would probably be better in this situation). At this point, though, it may not have been a big deal if the manager has not bothered reaching out again. I'd think in a true emergency requiring the employee, the manager would make repeated attempts across multiple channels to make contact.

Comment: @Ellesedil yes, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

A blunt(ish) but effective solution is to stop responding when you are not in the mood for it. This doesnt mean never reply, this means that when you feel a call would disturb you, you just switch phone off.

Very probably the boss will understand and do not disturb you (mine did), if he decides to confront you about it you got a massive headstart.